# Scarcely...When Vs Scarcely ...Than

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

**Scarcely** is usually combined with **When** but in the following line why does not it happens so?

> Scarcely had the small streamer bearing Mustafa Kamal entered the Black Sea 
>       than the authorities of Istanbul became suspicious of his intentions and 
>                    issued orders for the ship to be intercepted.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good example of inversion and I want to answer this question because it made me brush up on my knowledge.

Generally speaking, "than" can be either a preposition or a conjunction. However, the former is more familiar to the learners, me included.

Regarding your sentence, it's one of typical usage of "than" as a conjunction. In such cases, ***[than](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/than)*** is used to convey that something happens straight after the other one.

> *"scarcely was the work completed than it was abandoned."*

Comment: @Cardinal...if than is used to convey that something happens straight after the other one. then what does scarcely...when represents?isn't when & than convey same meaning whenever they combined with scarcely?

Comment: @M.NaeemAhmad I think both work fine. I don't see any significant difference between "when the authorities of ..." and "than the authorities of ..". But you should know that I am not a native person and there may be some slight difference.